# Extended gallery in Xamarin Forms

Tags: performance, xamarin.forms, image-gallery

I'm trying to implement the following in the Xamarin Forms:

- A gallery, which displays images in grid
- Image thumbnails are being downloaded from the server
- There may be as many as 10k images
- I need a mechanism, which will optimize downloading images (obviously loading 10k images at once is not an option)
- Each image will have some minimum description.

I'm stuck on the level of designing architecture for such solution under Xamarin Forms. Specifically:

- I have no idea, which control to use, which will display data the way I require
- I have no idea, how/when to decide, which images to download.

I already tried a control named `FlowListView`, which seemed OK, but behaved weirdly on UWP (part of window on which FLV was placed was not redrawn, resizing of window caused tons of GCs, which killed performance.

The best approach I can imagine for now is:

- Design custom composite control - ScrollView with a couple of Images and implement its "virtuality" manually - when user scrolls down, reuse some of the images
- Position images inside that ScrollView manually upon resizing or scrolling
- ScrollView will allow me to determine, when Image comes into view and then trigger downloading

This seems like an overkill for me. Isn't there simpler solution for this problem?

The core question: **Which control should I base my solution on, such that I'll be able to fulfill all requirements above?**